# Updating Parent and Child Columns when any Child is updated

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to write a query that will update all children and the parent when a certain column is modified on any child, but I'm confusing myself on how to do this in one db call.

Example Table:
id|sprocket_type

polymorphic_table:
parent_id|child_id

How would I modify all "sprocket_types" for the child queried, the parent, and all the siblings?

I'm hitting a wall, so far I have:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  parent_example(id, sprocket_type) AS
SELECT id, sprocket_type
    FROM example
    WHERE id = %(example_id)s
  ),
  all_examples(id, sprocket_type) AS (
    SELECT id, sprocket_type
    FROM example
    WHERE id = (
      SELECT id
      FROM parent_example
      WHERE id = %(example_id)s
    )
UPDATE example
SET sprocket_type = %(sprocket_type)s
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM all_examples
);
```

Comment: Please provide actual table definition (ddl) and sample data - as text , **no images**. Better still create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14). Also include the expected results of that data, also as text. Sample data should include rows to be updated and rows that are not updated.  *Provide as update to question nor as a comment.*

Answer (score 0):

We can use case statements and a sub query to update the columns differently for the parent and the child in the same update.

> ```
> create table example(
> id int primary key,
> name VARCHAR (10),
> scores int,
> pid int,
> child_scores int);
> insert into example values
> (1,'parent',0,null,0),
> (2,'child',0,1,0);
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> update example
> set scores = case
>   when id = 2 then scores + 5 
>   else scores end ,
> child_scores = case 
>   when id =
>   ( select pid from example 
>     where id = 2) 
>     then child_scores + 5
>   else child_scores end;
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from example;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name   | scores |  pid | child_scores
> -: | :----- | -----: | ---: | -----------:
>  1 | parent |      0 | null |            5
>  2 | child  |      5 |    1 |            0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3b6ce30be2b6a17b8c126daebc771044)*